# AJAX with Templating Loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

With a basic AJAX web app running locally, a Form POSTs data through Express/Node.js to MongoDB, and a button onClick responds in a rendering of the Mongo document(s) in a div-box.

**Using *[Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/)* for templating, onClick of the button is only returning a right-brace to appear in the html div-box.**

> }

..where the ajax posts the wrapper data in index.html:

```
<!-- For the Returned Fields -->
<div id="theResponse">

</div><!-- /.theResponse -->
```

**How can the jsonpCallback or Templating-Loop be edited to push all the MongoDB docs?**

wrapper.html:

```
{% for go in allDOCs %}
_wrapperGet('{"getting":"{{ keyName }}"}')
{% endfor %}
```

console.log(returnValue); is listing the mongoDB documents:

```
{"keyName":"Here's a Value!"}, {"keyName":"Here's another Value!"}
```

..from app.js

```
function getAllDOCs(res) {

    db.collection('dbCollectionName').find({}, {"_id":0}).toArray(function (err, docs) {

        console.log("Got the DOCs: " + docs);

        var returnValue = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++)
        {
            if (returnValue == "")
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + JSON.stringify(docs[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + ", " + JSON.stringify(docs[i]);
            }
            console.log(docs[i]);
        }

        console.log(returnValue);

        res.render('wrapper', { allDOCs: returnValue });

    });
}
```

index.html AJAX json parsing:

```
$.ajax({
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonpCallback: '_wrapperGet',
data: $('#theForm').serialize(),
type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:9090/insert",
    success: handleINSERTbuttonResponse,
});

function handleFINDbuttonResponse(data)
{
  // parse the json string
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#theResponse').append( jsonObject.getting );
}
```

Comment: There's a major difference in using JSONP and JSON, the first one is a script tag inserted in the DOM, with JSON wrapped in a function, and it doesn't look like that is what you're outputting on the server.

Comment: Really appreciate the insight. Have updated the app.js snippet to include more detail.. Any suggestions?